# In Rmagic how to add interline spacing on image with caption

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

Using Rmagic I am doing the following to create an image with a large amount of text

```
message="A very long auto wrapping sentence goes here"
  text_image = Image.read("caption:#{message}") do
  self.size="500x500"
  self.fill="white"
  self.background_color="#67c6ae"
  self.gravity=GravityType::WestGravity
  self.interline_spacing=5
end
```

This gives the error:

```
 undefined method `interline_spacing=' for #<Magick::Image::Info:0x00000101aad190> (NoMethodError)
```

How can I add line space here?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

It is a property of the `Draw` object, not the `Image` object. And it works with explicit line breaks. At least thats how its working for me:

```
image = Image.new(499,649)
message = "this\nmessage\nis\nmultiline"
draw = Draw.new
draw.annotate(image, 0,0,0,0,message) do
  self.gravity = NorthWestGravity
  self.pointsize = 32
  self.font_family = "Arial"
  self.font_weight = NormalWeight
  self.stroke = "none"
  self.fill = font_color
  self.interline_spacing = -5
end
```